# can I use a variable as a parameter name?

Tags: r

Say I put my cats in a matrix like this:

```
> cats <- cbind(fluffy=c(weight=1,length=2), muffin=c(3,4))
```

Which gives me:

```
       fluffy muffin
weight      1      3
length      2      4
```

Is there a way I can use a variable instead of specifying the name manually?

This doesn't work:

```
> name <- "whiskers"
> cbind(cats, name=c(5, 6))

       fluffy muffin name
weight      1      3    5
length      2      4    6
```

Nor does this:

```
> cbind(cats, `name`=c(5, 6))

       fluffy muffin name
weight      1      3    5
length      2      4    6
```

Nor does this:

```
> cbind(cats, $name=c(5, 6))

Error: unexpected '$' in "cbind(cats, $"
```

Is my only choice do do some nasty `do.call`ing?

```
> args <- list(cats, c(5,6))
> names(args)[2] <- name
> do.call(cbind, args)

       fluffy muffin whiskers
weight      1      3        5
length      2      4        6
```

Comment: What's wrong with `do.call`? You could also just add it as `new_col` and set the name in the next line. But `do.call` seems like a nice solution.

Comment: ..., i.e., `colnames(cats)[ncol(cats)] <- name`.

Comment: the only thing wrong with it is that I now have one line of code that actually "does something", and two lines of code that fiddle with column names

Comment: I guess you could do it the other way around... `whiskers <- c(5,6)` and then `cbind(cats, whiskers)`